# Azure logic app SFTP connection Error "A reference was made to a file which does not exist."

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I am able to connect SFTP using WinSCP tool providing same information. However, it's not working when I am trying to connect SFTP via Azure Logic app. I am getting an error message as follows:

> Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: A reference was made to a file which does not exist.

Screenshot:

[image]

I am not able to resolve this error.

Comment: The error message says nothing about connecting. It's about a specific file. So we need to know, what you are doing with the file. And if you can do the same thing with the same file using WinSCP.

Comment: I am not targeting any file when trying to connect to SFTP at first from logic app as well in WinSCP. WinSCP is working and i am able to connect but i am getting above error in azure logic app only.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is at the network perimeter. You are using WinSCP to connect to the SFTP server from your local network. Maybe that IP is already whitelisted for the port 22.

For Logic Apps to connect to your SFTP server, make sure the corresponding IP address is whitelisted for 22. Maybe Logic Apps is not able to reach the server on 22 port.

Comment: this could be a reason. i had call with Microsoft tech support solved it. it was able to make connection and saving connection as well. but still come up with this error. after connection having this error and referring respective directories  are working.